# Android Services equivalent in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, service

I am looking for something that is equivalent to `Services` in `Android`. As far as I have searched I haven't found anything useful. I found `Background Fetch` but according to my understanding it cannot be used long processes.
Here is what I want to use it for.
fetch a list of twitter user ids from our web server then auto-follow those usernames in background. As there are limits in Twitter API, so the process will be long possibly 3-4 hours. Is this possible on iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no long-running background mode for continuous execution of apps in iOS.
This doesn't really sound like the right task for a mobile device. Running a 3-4 hour background job would be bad for battery life.

You can implement the function on a server somewhere and use push notification to send updates to the device.

Comment: how about small tasks done like a simple POST request to Twitter every 5 minutes, is that possible?

Comment: You can use background fetch mode for something like that but it probably won't be executed every 5 minutes - more like every couple of hours. You can specify a refresh interval but this is a requested interval not a guaranteed interval

Comment: can you provide me with link for documentation and/or tutorial of background fetch for swift? I am not able to find it.

Comment: I don't know of one in Swift. This is a good one in Objective C - http://www.appcoda.com/ios7-background-fetch-programming/ .  There is really only one UIApplicationDelegate method that you need to implement - `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` so it isn't too hard to convert this to Swift

Answer (score 0):

An Android Service use case that is often cited is a background music service, which I have implemented as an exercise. It is not a given that a long running task actually will consume a lot of battery.  Rather, it appears Apple is guaranteeing that such an event cannot happen through API design.