# a solution to retrieve information when they're no internet connection

Tags: swift

On my app I have a form which the user can complete and send it to us with a SOAP request.

the form sended:

[image]

But I have a problem, I they're no internet connection I can't send the data by using my SOAP request.

So firstly I save the request in Core Data, so here it's ok... And when the user is on the app I do a scheduled request to see if they're a request in Core Data to send them.

But what about if the app is not running ? In Android I use background service, but with Apple it's impossible:

[Android Services equivalent in iOS Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959382/android-services-equivalent-in-ios-swift)

Someone have an idea to retrieve the data ?

Soap function:

```
func soapCall(fonction:String, soapMessageParamsTab:[SoapMessageParams], completion: @escaping (_ strData: NSString)-> ()/*, completion: @escaping (_ result: Int, _ resultContactWebId: Int)->()*/){
        let soapRequest = AEXMLDocument()
        let attributes = ["xmlns:SOAP-ENV" : "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "xmlns:ns1" : namespace, "xmlns:xsd" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "xmlns:xsi" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xmlns:SOAP-ENC" : "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/", "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle" : "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"]
        let envelope = soapRequest.addChild(name: "SOAP-ENV:Envelope", attributes: attributes)
        let body = envelope.addChild(name: "SOAP-ENV:Body")
        let sendLead = body.addChild(name: "ns1:"+fonction)

    for obj in soapMessageParamsTab {
        sendLead.addChild(name: obj.soapName, value: obj.soapValue, attributes: ["xsi:type" : "xsd:"+obj.soapType])
    }
        //sendLead.addChild(name: "xml", value: messageSoap, attributes: ["xsi:type" : "xsd:string"])


        let soapMessage = soapRequest.xmlString
        let messageSoapMinify = minify(soapMessage)


        //        URL Soap
        let urlString = soapServiceURL
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        var theRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

        //        Taille SoapMessage
        let msgLength = String(messageSoapMinify.characters.count)

        //        Soap Login
        let username = soapUsername
        let password = soapPassword
        let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password)
        let loginData: Data = loginString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
        let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)

        //        Requete Soap
        theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        theRequest.addValue("Keep-Alive", forHTTPHeaderField: "Connection")
        theRequest.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        theRequest.addValue("urn:ResponseAction", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
        theRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        theRequest.httpBody = messageSoapMinify.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        theRequest.addValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        //        print("Request is \(theRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields!)")

        let session = Foundation.URLSession.shared

        let task = session.dataTask(with: theRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

            if error != nil
            {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }

            //print("Response Login: \(response)")
            //print("Error Login: \(error)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
            //print("Body Login: \(strData)")

            completion(strData)
        })


        task.resume()

}
```

Comment: This is much more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Rob I think I'm in a difficult case, I don't want to send a message like "They're no internet connection, come later"

Comment: See [Downloading Content in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5) in _App Programming Guide for iOS: Background Operation._ While that section was written for downloads, it works equally well for uploads. And, frankly, you can consider your SOAP request to be a download, anyway (build the `URLRequest` and the "download" is the server response that you receive once the request is sent after internet connection is established).

Comment: If you google for "Background `NSURLSession` tutorial Swift" you'll undoubtedly find lots of examples of the topic.

Comment: @Rob I actually use URLSession in my SOAP request function

Comment: @Rob I use Foundation.URLSession.shared instead of NSURLSession...

Comment: `URLSession` is just the Swift 3 name for `NSURLSession` class. They're the same thing (though if you're looking at Swift code that references `NSURLSession`, it's likely Swift 2 code, so you'll have to convert it to Swift 3. For background session, you wouldn't use `shared`, but rather create a `URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: ...)` and then `session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)`. And you cannot use data tasks, but only upload/download tasks. And you have to use delegate, not completion handler methods. Etc.

Comment: It's beyond the scope of what we can reasonably cover in comments, which is why I suggest you google "background NSURLSession swift" or "background URLSession swift". It's not hard, but there are a lot of moving parts.

Comment: @Rob I'm using data task for my soap request... I just edited my question here is my soap function request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NSURLSession with background configuration you should be ok.
Note: If the app is explicitly killed by the user the scheduled request will be cancelled. This trick works just if the app was killed by the system for any reason (low memory, crash etc...). There is nothing you can do if the app was killed by the user. The background fetch might be a solution, but it will be decided by iOS if and when to awake the app for the opportunistic fetch. 
This could help you:
https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/01/13/ios9-background-execution/

**Edit:** 
This tutorial could be useful as well: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: Background fetch is not a good solution for this particular problem. Background `URLSession` is the way to go.

Comment: URLSession does not solve the problem of app killed by the user. I believe that a mix of both should meet Ben's needs. URLSession with background configuration for all the happy paths where the user does not kill the app. And Background fetch in case the app was explicitly killed by the user.

Comment: IIRC, if user kills app, it prevents further background fetch, too.

Comment: As developers we try to cover as much as we can. The fact that there are ways to prevent background fetch does not mean that we should not add the feature because it's useless for some users. Here we have to decide if to cover 80% of users that allows background fetch or if we should cover 0% of users that kills the app. I would rather try to get as many users I can. So URLSession + background fetch remains the best option. It does not cover 100% of cases, but it is all we have and for sure it covers all the cases that we can cover. There is nothing else we can do in my opinion.

Comment: I learned your link so it's talking about background configurations on a URLSession use... But I use data task, I can still found solution for that ? Look my edit to see my SOAP function please.

Comment: @Ben yes you can. You must create your own NSURLSession instead of using the shared one. And as configuration you should use the background configuration. Following the instructions in that link should help you to achieve that. 
Also take a look at the apple's official doc https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html
Or this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110458/nsurlsession-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: I'm gonna learn that... But to understand how it work, they're just a "background" configuration and this help to continue the "upload" even if the app close ?

Comment: As I said in my answer, if the app is closed by the user there is not much you can do. All the app related activities delegated to iOS get terminated. The only thing you can do is to add a background fetch capability to the app. iOS will awake your app periodically to let you "sync up" the app data. The URLSession with background configuration would cover those users that sends the app in background without killing it.

Comment: Ohhh okay ! Now I understand (sorry bad english comprehension) , I already use background fetch, See... I created a schedule task every 1 minutes with a local notification so I did: "Debug > Simulate Background Fetch" And here I see the notifications... So my background fetch is working ! But Why on simulator its working as well every minutes and when I test it on device it's look not working ? here is an interval ?

Comment: The interval you decide is the minimum one. On a real use case it's iOS that decides if and when to start the background fetch for your app, and the decision is made based on the usage of the app, and other user related behavior. This is to avoid unneeded power consumption. If the user does not use your app, for iOS it's useless to keep it up to date every minute because he opens it maybe once a week. The minimum interval just ensures you that no fetch is executed with intervals less than 1 minutes.

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza Okay so even if I set the interval to 1 minute when I try it to device only Apple set the interval by consummation... Another question so how Facebook does to work when app is killed by sending notification like "anniversary" or "friend request" ?

Comment: Push notifications. It's a totally different realm.

Comment: @GiuseppeLanza Okay So push notification is not in my use case... Thanks to you, I think if my scheduled task work in "Simulate Background Fetch", I will do tests in my real device and see if the data will be sent in a interval...

Comment: Yes, if it works on the Simulator there are good chances it will on the device. But You cannot predict how often will it happen. If this answered your question please mark the answer as accepted solution so that future developers with the same problem will have it. Cheers.

Comment: When the background fetch is running on interval, it's this function that is called : `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {` ?

Comment: The is awaken so this is one of the function called. in the launchOption you should get "why" the app was awaken, so that you should be able to understand that you must run your fetch function.
This link should help you: https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/01/13/ios9-background-execution/
check the section **Downloading remote content opportunistically**